# Jena export: Nesting elements or adding Description

Tags: java, jena

I want to export my jena database in file and when i use RDF/XML i am getting the objects with rdf:Description. When i use RDF/XML-ABBREV i am getting my objects with correct tag but they are nested.

```
dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\db\\");
Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel();

outputPath ="C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\file.xml";
writer = new FileWriter(outputPath);
model.write(writer, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
```

So, can anyone tell me how to fix this problem..

I tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439861/jena-model-converts-my-rdf-type-explicit-declaration-to-implicit-and-messes-with/53449930#53449930) but here is the response:

If i use:

```
RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, model, RDFFormat.RDFXML_PRETTY);
```

then it gives the prefixes fine but the objects are nested:

```
<cim:VoltageLevel rdf:about="urn:uuid:0#_2ecd8d06-9088-4adc-8800-80d5e73c1b94">
 <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>Domžale 20kV</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
 <cim:VoltageLevel.BaseVoltage>
  <cim:BaseVoltage rdf:about="urn:uuid:0#_5132f6db-1342-4f27-b701-2c446aba1590">
    <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>20kV</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
    <cim:BaseVoltage.nominalVoltage>20000</cim:BaseVoltage.nominalVoltage>
  </cim:BaseVoltage>
</cim:VoltageLevel.BaseVoltage>
<cim:VoltageLevel.highVoltageLimit>22000</cim:VoltageLevel.highVoltageLimit>
<cim:VoltageLevel.lowVoltageLimit>18000</cim:VoltageLevel.lowVoltageLimit>
<cim:VoltageLevel.Substation>
  <cim:Substation rdf:about="urn:uuid:0#_dc3cd19e-3ea5-4f61-89db-656ee1b8684a">
    <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>RTP Domžale</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
    <cim:Substation.Region rdf:resource="urn:uuid:0#_ee169401-9cef-417d-b01e-db2f9d3ce98b"/>
  </cim:Substation>
</cim:VoltageLevel.Substation>
```

If i use

```
model.write(System.out, "RDF/XML");
```

i am getting the objects like i want but instead of Description i want there to be the correct tags:

```
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="urn:uuid:0#_2ecd8d06-9088-4adc-8800-80d5e73c1b94">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name>Domžale 20kV</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://iec.ch/TC57/2013/CIM-schema-cim16#VoltageLevel"/>
<cim:VoltageLevel.BaseVoltage rdf:resource="urn:uuid:0#_5132f6db-1342-4f27-b701-2c446aba1590"/>
<cim:VoltageLevel.highVoltageLimit>22000</cim:VoltageLevel.highVoltageLimit>
<cim:VoltageLevel.lowVoltageLimit>18000</cim:VoltageLevel.lowVoltageLimit>
 <cim:VoltageLevel.Substation rdf:resource="urn:uuid:0#_dc3cd19e-3ea5-4f61-89db-656ee1b8684a"/>
 </rdf:Description>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439861/jena-model-converts-my-rdf-type-explicit-declaration-to-implicit-and-messes-with/53449930#53449930 for how to write with a different variation of RDF/XML.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: By "correct tags", you mean the RDF type as the outer tag? See options for RDF/XMl output https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdfxml_howto.html#advanced-rdfxml-output or you may need to use XSLT. The role of writing RDf/XMl isn't to produce output for an arbitrary XML schema, it's to produce RDF. Some times, it will need post-processing.